# php exec file runs from terminal, not from browser

Tags: php, macos, exec

I have a program that should start my screensaver:

```
<?php
$cmd='automator /Users/myusername/Library/Services/Start_Screensaver.workflow';
shell_exec($cmd);
?>
```

When I run it with

```
php index.php
```

it works fine but when I try to run it from a browser I always get the following error in the apache error_log file:

```
The workflow file does not exist.
```

Which I find very weird since I do have the correct path starting from the root folder. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Also, although I'm pretty sure apache is setup correctly on my mac I can only acces the web pages via the ip adres of my mac on my mac itself. So when I go to my Mac's IP on my phone for example it can't load the page, but when I go to my Raspberry Pi's IP address (which also runs apache) it works fine.

Edit: To be clear, the point of this is not to start the screensaver on my Mac but to start it remotely from my phone inside Tasker

Edit: I put the automator workflow file in the same directory and did

```
sudo chmod 777 start_screensaver.workflow
```

and now I'm getting the following errors:

```
2015-12-24 19:12:26.376 automator[2313:462937] Not loading action at /Library/Automator/Create Table from Data in Workbook.action: No bundleIdentifier.
2015-12-24 19:12:26.377 automator[2313:462937] Not loading action at /Library/Automator/Save Outlook Messages as Files.action: No bundleIdentifier.
2015-12-24 19:12:26.677 automator[2313:462937] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:26.678 automator[2313:462937] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:26.679 automator[2313:462937] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:26.680 automator[2313:462937] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:27.692 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Not loading action at /Library/Automator/Create Table from Data in Workbook.action: No bundleIdentifier.
2015-12-24 19:12:27.692 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Not loading action at /Library/Automator/Save Outlook Messages as Files.action: No bundleIdentifier.
2015-12-24 19:12:27.757 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Script Monitor is missing or damaged: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The application “ScriptMonitor” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810)." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///System/Library/CoreServices/ScriptMonitor.app/, NSLocalizedDescription=The application “ScriptMonitor” could not be launched because a miscellaneous error occurred (OSStatus -10810)., NSUnderlyingError=0x7f80f3411190 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10810 "kLSUnknownErr: Unexpected internal error"}}
2015-12-24 19:12:27.758 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Script Monitor is missing or damaged
2015-12-24 19:12:27.843 Automator Runner[2314:462973] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:27.844 Automator Runner[2314:462973] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:27.844 Automator Runner[2314:462973] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:27.846 Automator Runner[2314:462973] CFPasteboardRef CFPasteboardCreate(CFAllocatorRef, CFStringRef) : failed to create global data
2015-12-24 19:12:27.872 Automator Runner[2314:462980] warning: failed to get scripting definition from /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app; it may not be scriptable.
2015-12-24 19:12:27.966 Automator Runner[2314:462980] Scripting Bridge could not launch application /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app.
2015-12-24 19:12:27.997 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Error writing cache to /Library/WebServer/Library/Caches/com.apple.automator.actionCache-user-standardLocations.plist: The folder “com.apple.automator.actionCache-user-standardLocations.plist” doesn’t exist.
2015-12-24 19:12:30.830 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Error writing cache to /Library/WebServer/Library/Caches/com.apple.automator.actionCache-system-standardLocations.plist: The folder “com.apple.automator.actionCache-system-standardLocations.plist” doesn’t exist.
2015-12-24 19:12:31.148 Automator Runner[2314:462973] Error writing cache to /Library/WebServer/Library/Caches/com.apple.automator.actionCache-bundleLocations.plist: The folder “com.apple.automator.actionCache-bundleLocations.plist” doesn’t exist.
```

Comment: I am going to just say that this is not what PHP is designed for.  That said, it is likely *possible*, with some extensive working knowledge, to do this, however I would suggest against it.  Consider all of the implications: If I were to know your IP, I could launch your screen-saver.  :-/ I am sure you do not want to write a back-door into your own computer...  A solution (with working knowledge) would be write a cron script, and touch a file, if the cron detects the file, it launches the task.  There would be more to it, but that should be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Apache user does not have access to that directory. When you run php scripts from cli, you run them as `myusername`, but, once you open it from browser, it's a [different user](https://serverfault.com/questions/152175/apache-runs-as-which-user-group-under-os-x-10-6) (`_www`).

So, you need to make sure that the file is accessible by the `_www` user. Setting permissions to `777` for that file would probably do the thing.

P.S.: btw @Mike is absolutely right that you should rethink the way you're using your script.

### UPD

The screensaver launches, that's cool. So, the issue is all about permissions. So, you can either try to run it with php built-in server

```
php -S localhost:8000 index.php
```

Or configure apache and [change the apache user](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46062/change-the-user-apache-runs-as).

Alternatively, you can move all your screensaver-related stuff yo a publicly accessible dir, but, again, this may potentially cause some security flaws.

Comment: OK thank you! I will definitely look into cron but isn't apache set so it can only be accessed over your local IP by default? Going to my local IP when in a browser brings up the page, going to my public IP does not. I'm sorry if this is a dumb question I don't know that much about networking.

Comment: @JanG I don't think that using apache server to launch a screensaver is a good idea unless you want to start it remotely (from phone or whatever). Using cron to schedule screensavers seems also weird to me. I think you should just create a demon that would hang in the background and launch the screensaver.

Comment: Yes, I should've probably mentioned this but the whole point of the was to launch my screensaver remotely.

Comment: I used the "sudo chmod 777 index.php" command and it still causes the same issue.  (P.S. I should've said this from the beginning but the point of this is not to launch the screensaver from my Mac but to launch it from my phone inside Tasker).

Comment: @JanG you should chmod not the php file but the screensaver workfliw file ;)

Comment: Changing the user to my main account worked, thank you!